# How can I determine the type of bifurcation I have found?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I was tasked with finding and classifying the bifurcation of the following system:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = rx(x+1)-1$$

I have found that the bifurcation occurs when $r=1$, with equilibrium points at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{r}-1$, but I am not sure how to determine the type of bifurcation it is. I have created a plot of the equilibrium points against r, but it looks nothing like any other plots I have seen that give the type of bifurcation. Is there a way to find the type of bifurcation it is analytically, or how can I otherwise determine the type of the bifurcation?

Comment: What is "burification"?  Is it related to "bifurcation" somehow?

Comment: It would be good if you could be more attentive to the spelling.  That would save a lot of yours as well as others' time.

Comment: Mmm, [burfi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burfi)-fication...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equilibrium points satisfy $x^2 + x - 1/r = 0$, with solutions
$$
x_\pm = -\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{r}}\, .
$$
The Jacobian $J(x) = r (2x + 1)$ evaluated at the equilibrium points reads
\begin{aligned}
J(x_\pm) &= \pm r\sqrt{{1}+{4}/{r}} \\ &= \pm \text{sgn}(r)\sqrt{r(r+{4})}\, ,
\end{aligned}
where $\text {sgn}$ denotes the sign function.
Therefore,

- if $r>0$, $x_+$ is an unstable equilibrium while $x_-$ is asymptotically stable;
- if $-4<r<0$, there is no equilibrium;
- if $r<-4$, $x_-$ is an unstable equilibrium while $x_+$ is asymptotically stable.

Two bifurcations occur: one at $r=0$ and one at $r= -4$, as illustrated on this diagram:

[image: equilibrium]

One can remark that these bifurcations are of [saddle-node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle-node_bifurcation) type.

Comment: What software did you use to produce this output? :)

Comment: @Evgeny This is a Matlab plot, but Maple, Mathematica, Python and many more can be used for a similar result

Comment: Thanks! I was curious because your plot follows usual notation for stable and unstable regimes, thought that you might have used bifurcation software for it :)